# Missing External Function in IEFrame.DLL and SHLWAPI.DLL when referencing SharpSVN

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, dependency-management, sharpsvn

Note: This section contains incorrect information - skip to the update below for details.  This section left in for historical purposes.

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio 2008 targeting .NET 3.5 that references SharpSVN.  When I make a call into SvnClient.Export, I get an exception that Marshal.GetExceptionCode tells me is 0xc06d007e.  This seems to be caused by a bad DLL.  I have tracked (with the Dependency Walker) that DLL to two culprits:  IEFRAME.DLL and SHLWAPI.DLL.  They are missing the following export functions:

SHLWAPI.DLL: #270
IEFRAME.DLL: #141, #159, #160

I also initially had a missing DLL that was fixed by adding %ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer to the path.  I do not recall the DLL name.

This is a fresh install of Visual Studio 2008, SharpSVN 1.7002.1998.12257.

I can run the "svn" command that is provided with SharpSVN to export from our repository, so I am leaning toward a solution/project configuration/reference problem.

How do I fix this error?

---

*Update:  I have refined my understanding of this problem.  The SHLWAPI and IEFRAME issues appear to be a normal condition - User32.dll has the same behavior.  I modified my environment in the following ways:

Environment variable [SVN_SSH] set to TortoisePlink [C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe]

Updated uri target to use current username:

```
SvnUriTarget uriTarget = 
    new SvnUriTarget("svn+ssh://" + Environment.UserName + "@myserver/mypath");
```

With this configuration, I can successfully export when running this code as part of the WPF application.  However, I still get errors when running as part of a MSTest project.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.\r\n   
at svn_client_export5(Int32* , SByte* , SByte* , svn_opt_revision_t* , svn_opt_revision_t* , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , svn_depth_t , SByte* , svn_client_ctx_t* , apr_pool_t* )\r\n
at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Export(SvnTarget from, String toPath, SvnExportArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result) in g:\\dist\\src\\sharpsvn\\commands\\export.cpp:line 100
at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Export(SvnTarget from, String toPath, SvnExportArgs args) in g:\\dist\\src\\sharpsvn\\commands\\export.cpp:line 66
at SimulationManager.Model.SubversionInterface.Export() in C:\\Users\\phines\\Documents\\Projects\\SimulationManager\\SimulationManager\\SimulationManager\\Model\\SubversionInterface.cs:line 43
```

I suspect this is due to a reliance on the presentation framework, but would still like to know if there is a way to get this working in a GUI-less way.

Comment: Maybe IEFrame.DLL and SHLWAPI.DLL have some external dependencies.  You should read their documentation

Comment: I have since discovered this is a "normal" condition, user32.dll has the same problem, removing sharpsvn has no effect on this, and the call to export is still failing when it is put back in.  It looks like this symptom is not part of the problem, but I still have the problem with the call to SvnClient.Export failing with C06d007e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors with IEFrame and SHLWAPI are normal problems that depends reports as errors, but do not acutally cause the error.  In my case, the error was caused by using SharpSVN in a non-user interface project.  When moved to a WPF project, it worked as expected.

I have changed strategies to call a command shell "svn" application to achieve UI-less automation.